# Install Rekonq 1.0

Tags: installation, fedora, kde

I would like install Rekonq 1.0 on Fedora 17, using KDE 4.8.5. At the moment, this version of Rekonq isn't available in the repositories. Actually, I've the version 0.9.2. Anyone knows how can I update my app?

Thanks!

Comment: -1: My answer was the 1st hit from a google search, you don't seem to have tried anything before asking here.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the [source](http://rekonq.kde.org/) from here.

Then, follow the instructions in the downloaded archive (see the file INSTALL). Bear in mind that you may have to install other development packages to get it to compile if it is linked to newer versions that what you have installed.